# Vertically grouping of UML symbols

Tags: plantuml

When you group things `together` in PlantUML, they tend to be placed next to each other *horizontally.*

Is there a way to group them `together` *vertically?*

Comment: Your question needs a concrete context. Can you show something that works, but not the way you want? Did you try `left to right direction`?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator This did what I wanted to do. Thank you! :') I've noticed that if we have `top to bottom direction`, it groups things horizontally, and if we have `left to right direction`, it groups things vertically. And it makes sense, I guess.